# How to treat a returned/stored string like a raw string in Python?

Tags: python, string, escaping

I am trying to `.split()` a hex string i.e. `'\xff\x00'` to get a list i.e. `['ff', '00']`

This works if I split on a raw string literal i.e. `r'\xff\x00'` using `.split('\\x')` but not if I split on a hex string stored in a variable or returned from a function (which I presume is not a raw string)

How do I convert or at least 'cast' a stored/returned string as a raw string?

Comment: btw, there are no "raw" strings in Python, there are just convenient literals in the `r''` form (for regexps and Windows paths as a rule).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = '\xff\x00'
y = ['%02x' % ord(c) for c in x]
print y
```

Output:

```
['ff', '00']
```

Comment: This might help:  `len(x) == 2`; `'ff' in x == False`

Comment: Also: `'%02x' % ord('k') == '6b'

Comment: Ah ok, so each hex value is a 'single' character. `ord()` returns the integer worth i.e. ff -> 255. The `x` in a Python string format renders the hex representation of an integer (sans the `\x`) and the `0` pads it with zeroes and the `2` specifies the width. See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Comment: This is often useful when dealing with binary data which needs to be converted to hex... `x.encode("hex")` which prints `'ff00'`.  Likewise `'ff00'.decode("hex")` is `'\xff\x00'`.

Comment: Nick—That's probably worth posting as a separate answer.  Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in the spirit of the original question:

```
x = '\xff\x00'
eval("r"+repr(x)).split('\\x')
```

It will return the same thing as `r'\xff\x00'.split('\\x')`: `['', 'ff', '00']`.

Comment: Although that works for this specific example, it fails for many other strings. For example, x = '\x20\x20' gives ['  '] instead of ['20', '20'].

Comment: Yes, it will work only for non-printable characters so it's not really a good solution.